# Rails double quotes always escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was configuring syntax highlighting for my blog when I came across this problem. '"' is always escaped... Here is my code:

```
# in application_helper.rb
def coderay(content)
  defaults = {...}      

  content.gsub!(/\<pre\>\<code class=\"(.+?)\"\>(.+?)\<\/code\><\/pre\>/m) do
    CodeRay.scan($2, $1).div(defaults)
  end
end

def markdown(text)
  options = {...}    

  renderer = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, options)
  coderay(renderer.render(text)).html_safe
end

#in view file
...
<%= markdown @post.body %>
...
```

Everything works fine except that double quotes (") are always escaped. Tried many methods but none worked.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are the quotes escaped? Do you have sample output?

Comment: @Mark " => &quot;  It just happened inside <code> tag, so I guess there should be something wrong with coderay method.

Comment: Maybe the output of coderay isn't meant to be in a `<pre>`?

Comment: Yes, it is. The output html: `<div class="CodeRay">
  <div class="code"><pre><span class="line-numbers"><a href="#n1" name="n1">1</a></span>puts &amp;quot;test&amp;quot;
</pre></div>` The `&amp;quot;` part should actually be `&quot;` I don't know why the '&' is escaped again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used a less "elegant" way to solve this problem. Just in case someone else encounters this problem too.

I created a new method as follows:

```
  def unescape(content)
    content.gsub!(/(&quot;|&#39;|&amp;|&lt;|&gt;)/) do
      case $1
        when "&quot;"
          '"'
        when "&#39;"
          "'"
        when "&amp;"
          "&"
        when "&lt;"
          "<"
        when "&gt;"
          ">"
      end
    end
  end
```

Generally, this method just does some unescape.

Before doing CodeRay.scan($2, $1).div(defaults), I used the unescape method to unescape $2, then everything goes fine.

If someone knows a better way, please tell me.